# R survey sackage method for replicating SUDAAN proc crosstabs SEROW

Tags: r, standard-error, survey, percentage, two-way

I have been using SUDAAN's proc crosstabs to generated weighted crosstabs, percentages, and standard errors for counts and percentages.  I'm trying to replicate this functionality in R and have gotten everything but the standard error for the percentages (SEROW).  I'm using the following command to calculate the row percentages:

```
Design <- svrepdesign(data=DataFrame , repweights="PSTOTWGT[1-64]", weights=~PSTOTWGT, type="Fay", rho=.2999)

Percentages <- prop.table(svytable(~Variable+Stratifier, Design), margin=2)
```

My Variable and Stratifier have 6 and 3 levels respectively.  Is there a way to calculate standard errors for these percentages using the R survey package?  If not, is there another R package that can generate the percentages?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think you are computing proportions rather than percentages.

Can you check the link below?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426055/r-how-to-calculate-proportion-using-survey-package/49692059#49692059

The link seems to suggest that a command like this:

```
svymean(~interaction(Variable, Stratified), Design)
```

should give you the proportions corresponding to each combination of values of Variable and Stratified as well as correspnding standard errors.

On the other hand, a command like this:

```
svytotal(~interaction(Variable, Stratified), Design)
```

should give you the counts correspnding to each combination of values of Variable and Stratified as well as standard errors.

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you Isabella, I'm definitely not creating proportions.  Both my Variable and Stratifier are categorical variables, so dividing their values isn't valid.  For example, my variable is income level coded as 1 (below poverty), 2 (at poverty), 3 (2 x poverty) and my stratifier is age group codes as 1 (< 65), 2 (65-84), 3 (85+).  The svytable command gives the the percentages of poverty for each age group, each adding to 100%.  SUDAAN also gives the Standard Errors, which do not appear to be sqrt((p * (1-p))/n).

Comment: Not near a computer, but if the commands I suggested above work as advertised in that link, you can simply multiply the results they provide by 100 to convert from proportion of responses to percentage of responses falling into each combination of categories of your two categorical variables.

Comment: I wonder if the SUDAAN documentation specifies what formula it uses for standard error computation - then you would be able to implement it in R by brute force.  Not sure what formula is used by the above commands in R.